# Working with the Youtube-Api

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I have several Tutorial Videos on Youtube and i want to 
include them into my Application. So i have a fix set
of Youtube-URL's.

I want to show a list of these videos for that i somehow
need to get the thumbnail, the title and the description
of each Youtube-URL and to show it. When the user clicks 
on a item of the listview i want the selected youtube
video to be played inside my application.

Unfortunately i cant find example which are showing how
to achieve these things. playing youtube videos is easy
but i dont know how to get the thumbnail, title and descritpion
of given youtube url's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow the [link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads/) . They have very nice demo and explanation .

Comment: Yes i already found that but unfortunately nothing of these demos is working. The app is crashing when i want to start a demo. none of it is working.

Comment: have you registered your app on api console

Comment: what do you mean? i downloaded the samples from the link you provided, imported it into my eclipse and started it on my android device.

Comment: for setting up project follow this link https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/setup

Comment: i dont understand that. its the code from google. where should i place the api key inside the provided google code?